# Create Terraform Output When Count Enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to create an outputs.tf for a resource in Terraform which has count set. When count is 1, all works fine, however when count is 0, it does not:

If I create the output like this

```
output "ec2_instance_id" {
  value = aws_instance.ec2_instance.id
}
```

It errors

> because aws_instance.ec2_instance has "count" set, its attributes must
>   be accessed on specific instances.

However, changing it to

```
output "ec2_instance_id" {
  value = aws_instance.ec2_instance[0].id
}
```

works for a count of 1, but when count is 0 gives

> aws_instance.ec2_instance is empty tuple
>
> The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Therefore I saw [this post](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22480#issuecomment-521762472) and tried

```
output "ec2_instance_id" {
  value = aws_instance.ec2_instance[count.index].id
}
```

but that gives

> The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks,
>   and only when the "count" argument is set.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you only care about 1 or 0 instances, you can access the whole list can use the [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) `aws_instance.ec2_instance[*].id` with the `join` function and an empty string, which results in the ID or an empty string depending on whether the resource was created or not.

```
output "ec2_instance_id" {
  value = join("", aws_instance.ec2_instance[*].id)
}
```

Example:

```
variable "thing1" {
  default = [
    { id = "one" }
  ]
}

variable "thing2" {
  default = []
}

output "thing1" {
  value = join("", var.thing1[*].id)
}

output "thing2" {
  value = join("", var.thing2[*].id)
}
```

Results in

```
➜ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

thing1 = one
thing2 =
```